# If block execute with a false value, using substring and equals method

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, substring

I need to set a variable false, If the string starts with '1', but following code  returns me a true value? i tried the word "apple". Is there any problem with my code?

```
String msgName=request.getParameter("msgName");
boolean insideIf=false; 

if(msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));
    {
        insideIf=true;
                System.out.println("if status :"+msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));

    } System.out.println("insideIf :"+insideIf);
```

Comment: you already got the answer, so only one more suggestion, use charAt to check a single character myString.charAt(0) == '1'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is :-)
You've got a semicolon after your if

```
String msgName=request.getParameter("msgName");
boolean insideIf=false; 

if(msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"))
    {
        insideIf=true;
                System.out.println("if status :"+msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));

    } System.out.println("insideIf :"+insideIf);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if(msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));
```

is actually **executing an empty statement** if the condition yields true - and later, it always invokes the block:

```
{
    insideIf=true;
            System.out.println("if status :"+msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));

}
```

Solutions:

1. [less elegant] - remove the `;`
2. You can always just set `insideIf = msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1");` - there is **no really reason for the if-statement**, you just need the boolean value of the expression!

   - You can also use the [`String.startsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) to improve readability even more!

Answer (score 4):

You have added a semi-colon to the end of the if-statement , so your if-else condition is not executing at all.
Here is what i think will work

```
String msgName=request.getParameter("msgName");
 boolean insideIf=false; 

if(msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"))
{
    insideIf=true;
            System.out.println("if status :"+msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));

} System.out.println("insideIf :"+insideIf);
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps choose for:

myString.startsWith('1');

I think that doesn't need an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

this is the error line

```
if(msgName.substring(0,1).equals("1"));
```

there should not be ";' after if statement. since you  have placed ";" so this if loop is ending here and it is executing the next line sequentially.
i hope it is self explaing .
regards
Anil